# What is copula regression basicly?

Tags: probability, regression, regression-analysis

Iam learning copula regression. Could you help me? What is copula regression basicly? Which studies I can read for learning this? What is your simple definition for copula regression?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Just google this for you: http://www.variancejournal.org/issues/05-01/45.pdf After skimming the article, basically you are allowing the variables in your regression model to have a more general dependency structure, rather than those multivariate normal, etc.